# How to list amazon orders through ASIN

Tags: amazon-mws

Is there a way to get the orders only is you have an ASIN?

Right now what I am doing is to fetching all the orders through **ListOrder** (no ASIN returned here. but I can use AmazonOrderId) and then filtering/matching them out one by one through **GetOrder** (gives back the ASIN if you send AmazonOrderId). However this is an ugly way to do this as it takes a long process to filter out the desired Order.

I am wondering if anyone has a workaround for this? As I cannot to see any solution in the MWS docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can request a `_GET_ORDERS_DATA_` report. It lists all orders in a specified time period and contains ASINs for each order item. This means you can do it in just four requests (RequestReport, GetReportRequestList, GetReportList, GetReport, as outlined in "Managing Reports" in the [Amazon Marketplace Web Service Developer Guide (Version 2009-01-01)](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mws/doc/bde/feeds/v20090901/en_US/MWSDeveloperGuide._V196696164_.pdf).

However you'll still have to do quite some filtering on that data to get only the orders that contain a certain ASIN.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Im trying this now. I can see in RequestReport that it is now _SUBMITTED_. How long do I wait before the report is _DONE_?

Comment: @RussellGutierrez It will go from `_SUBMITTED_` to `_PROCESSING_`, then switch to `_DONE_`. The amount of time this takes depends on the complexity of your request and the current load on the servers. In my experience reports usually complete in a few minutes, but I've (rarely) seen them queued for hours.

Comment: I don't see ASIN on the report. Only SKU and AmazonOrderItemCode

Comment: @RussellGutierrez I assumed you had the data available to link SKUs to ASINs. If you don't, you can call the Product API to resolve an ASIN to your SKU - e.g. through `GetMyPriceForASIN`